# Why am I getting a permission denied error on docker/aws eb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I don't know why but I cannot seem to figure out why this is happening. I can build and run the docker image locally.

Recent Events:

```
2015-05-25 12:57:07 UTC+1000    ERROR   Update environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.
2015-05-25 12:57:07 UTC+1000    INFO    New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
2015-05-25 12:57:04 UTC+1000    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2015-05-25 12:57:04 UTC+1000    ERROR   [Instance: i-4775ec9b] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)... run Docker container: vel="fatal" msg="Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 02c057b331bf3a3d912bf064f1dca3e00c95746b5748c3c4a28a5c6b452ff335: [8] System error: exec: \"bin/app\": permission denied" . Check snapshot logs for details. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/04run.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
2015-05-25 12:57:03 UTC+1000    ERROR   Failed to run Docker container: vel="fatal" msg="Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 02c057b331bf3a3d912bf064f1dca3e00c95746b5748c3c4a28a5c6b452ff335: [8] System error: exec: \"bin/app\": permission denied" . Check snapshot logs for details.
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8u45-jre
MAINTAINER Terence Munro <terry@zenkey.com.au>
ADD ["opt", "/opt"]
WORKDIR /opt/docker
RUN ["chown", "-R", "daemon:daemon", "."]
USER daemon
ENTRYPOINT ["bin/app"]
EXPOSE 9000
```

Dockerrun.aws.json:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "9000"
    }
  ],
  "Volumes": []
}
```

Additional logs as attachment at: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=181270

Any help is extremely appreciated.

---

[@nick-humrich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30431599/why-am-i-getting-a-permission-denied-error-on-docker-aws-eb?noredirect=1#comment48975568_30431599) suggestion of trying `eb local run` worked. So using `eb deploy` ended up working.

I had previously been uploading through the web interface.

Initially using `eb deploy` was giving me a `ERROR: TypeError :: data must be a byte string` but I found this [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/1240) which was resolved by uninstalling pyopenssl.

So I don't know why the web interface was giving me permission denied perhaps something to do with the zip file?

But anyway I'm able to deploy now thank you.

Comment: Have you tried launching it locally `eb local run`?

Comment: I didn't know you could do that, so that's cool but yeah it works locally using `eb local run`.. Still getting permission denied when I upload it though :(

Comment: What is bin/app? I assume its an executable but when you upload (as a zip), its loosing the permission bits. What's the system you're using locally? What about running it with the program that is supposed to execute it eg. ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "bin/app"] in case of bash script.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem running Docker on Elastic Beanstalk. When I pointed CMD in the Dockerfile to a shell script (`/path/to/my_script.sh`), the EB deployment would fail with
`/path/to/my_script.sh: Permission denied.`

Apparently, even though I had run `RUN chmod +x /path/to/my_script.sh` during the Docker build, by the time the image was run, the permissions had been changed. Eventually, to make it work I settled on:

`CMD ["/bin/bash","-c","chmod +x /path/to/my_script.sh && /path/to/my_script.sh"]`